# Wired Connection: Device Not Ready/Cable Unplugged

Tags: 12.04, networking

I used to have Windows XP in my PC but it was getting slow, So I completely formatted my Computer (Except for the Partition with my files) and Installed Ubuntu 12.04. (I'm typing this on another PC)

When I start up my PC, on the top right corner, it says "Not Connected" I have an Ethernet Adapter on my PC and it's plugged into an Ethernet switch, which is plugged into the Router. The Switch's lights light up, indicating that the computer is connected to it. Since the switch is connected to the Router, the Router has only one light on.

When I right-click the Network Connections thing, it says Wired Network Device not Ready. If I go to "System Settings" and Click on Network, Under Wired, It says "Wired : Cable UnPlugged. Hardware Address: 94:OC:6D:85:C8:B8" It is plugged in, though.

This is what I get if I 'ifconfig'

```
janith@ubuntu-Desktop:~$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 94:0c:6d:85:c8:b8
          inet addr: fe80::960c::6dff:fe85::c8b8/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1
          RX Packets:775 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX Packets:40 errors: 0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:99977 (99.9KB)  TX Bytes:7125 (7.1KB)
          Interrupt:18 Base address:0xbc00

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1 Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING MTU:16436 Metric:1
          RX Packets:2840 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX Packets:2840 errors: 0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueulen:0
          RX bytes:231848 (231.8KB)  TX Bytes:231848 (231.8KB)

janith@ubuntu-Desktop:-$
```

And lspci

```
janith@Ubuntu-Desktop:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 82915G/P/GV/GL/PL/910GL Memory Controller Hub      (rev 04)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82915G/P/GV/GL/PL/910GL PCI Express Root Port (rev 04)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 82915G/GV/910GL Integrated    Graphics Controller (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) High Definition Audio Controller (rev 03)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) PCI Express Port 1 (rev 03)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) PCI Express Port 2 (rev 03)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) PCI Express Port 3 (rev 03)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) PCI Express Port 4 (rev 03)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) USB UHCI #1 (rev 03)
00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) USB UHCI #2     (rev 03)
00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) USB UHCI #3    (rev 03)
00:1d.3 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) USB UHCI #4 (rev 03)
00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller (rev 03)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev d3)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FR (ICH6/ICH6R) LPC Interface Bridge (rev 03)
00:1f.1 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) IDE Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FW (ICH6/ICH6W) SATA Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) SMBus Controller (rev 03)
06:01.0 Modem: Motorola SM56 Data Fax Modem (rev 04)
06:02.0 Ethernet controller: Sundance Technology Inc / IC Plus Corp IC Plus IP100A   Integrated 10/100 Ethernet MAC + PHY (rev 31)
janith@Ubuntu-Desktop:~$
```

I know my Adapter is a TP Link, and the Windows Installation Disk says: TM-IP5600.

Help? If I need to install the driver, where do I get it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the cable that connects from your router to your switch  to connect the system directly to the router. You may have a bad cable between the switch and the system or you may have dropped a port on your switch. The indicator light doesn't guarantee a proper connection on all pairs. Based on the excessive number of errors in your question this is the first place to look.